# How can I add a custom file(built for every created project) in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I want to create a plug-in for Eclipse in which every custom project I create has a specific template and specific files. I managed to create the template(folder1/folder_name1, folder1/folder_name2, folder2/folder_name1, etc), but I am still trying to figure it out on how to make sure that when I create this type of project, some custom files are created(namely in folder_name1 and folder_name2). How would you think is the best way to do it?

I have tried using IFile, but I'm not really sure on how to use it.

This is the function that creates a project:

```
public static IProject createProject(String projectName, URI location) {
    Assert.isNotNull(projectName);
    Assert.isTrue(projectName.trim().length() > 0);

    IProject project = createBaseProject(projectName, location);
    try {
        addNature(project);

        String[] paths = {
                "folder1/folder_name1", //$NON-NLS-1$
                "folder1/folder_name2",
                "folder2/folder_name1",
                "folder2/folder_name2"}; //$NON-NLS-1$
        addToProjectStructure(project, paths);
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        project = null;
    }

    return project;
}
```

I expect that a file(let's name it test.cpp) it's created in folder_name1 and folder_name2 for each folder1/2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have project object ie `IProject project = createBaseProject(projectName, location);`
you can use the following code snippet

.... other code ...

```
IFile templateFile = project.getFile("/projectPath/folder1/folder_name1/templateFile1.txt"); 
String fileContents = "Template File Contents";//You can get the contents from source
InputStream source = new ByteArrayInputStream(contents.getBytes());
templateFile .create(source, false, null);
```

I hope in this you can create file specific to project folder. You can also get answers from others.